# How to share the current status of an application in development

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, share, collaboration

I am going to develop an iOS application for a customer of mine and I would like to make him constantly up-to-date during the development phase. In order to do so, I am looking for a tool which should allow me to share the current status of the application with my customer. The goal is to allow my customer to personally run the latest prototype of the application on a kind of simulator/emulator or on his own device (either iPhone or iPad).
Is that possible? Is there a tool (or a set of tools) which I can use to do so?

In case it is not possible, as far as I know the only alternative is to take screenshots or record videos, right? Just let me know if I am mistaken.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you want your customer to actually use the current state of just see the current state of your application?

Comment: You could use a distributed version control system (like `git`) on your source code.

Comment: @Bartu I want my customer to actually use the current state of the application

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch actually I am looking for a simpler way. Git is a great tool but I fear it can be too complex for a standard user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way, I know of, is [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/).

This allows you to upload an AdHoc build of your app to there server and allow you customer to download it.

They even supply an SDK which can alert the user that a new version of the app is available also you add some debug functionality to the build (reading crash reports).

Comment: Sounds interesting! I will test it and I will let you know! Thanks :-)

Comment: One last question: in this case does "AdHoc" mean that the build which my customer is going to test should not be the complete one but a limited one? I guess that the goal of creating this limited build is to avoid that my customer can steal the app and publish it on his own, right?

Comment: Nope, it means you can distribute it without submitting it to Apple's App Store.

Comment: @rdurand said it just an build that is limited to an number of device you can install it on. You create the adhoc provisioning profile on the devleopers site over at apple.com, there you add the UDID of all the device you want to able to run your buil. Since this is a build no code is supplied and the customer can't build it's onw version.

Comment: BTW, you can distribute your app via ad-hoc without TestFlight. Create the ad-hoc provisioning profile, archive your app, select "Save for ad-hoc distribution", put both the .ipa and .plist files created on a server, and add an html page with a simple link to your ipa's url. I also have used TestFlight. It's great for beta-testing, you can have online logs and stuff, but if you only need to have your client test your app, you may not need all those features... But it's a great tool :)

Comment: @rckoenes thank you very much for the explanation. In order to create a AdHoc build, do I need to be a registered developer and pay the yearly license?

Comment: Yes, you will need to have a paid developers license.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do, one elegant solution would be to use a continuous integration server to pull the code from your repository, make an adhoc build and place it somewhere publicly accessible.

The whole solution can take some time to set up and depends quite a lot on how is your development environment. In my company we are actually doing it with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and some shell scripting. If you Google a little bit about continuous integration of iOS projects with Jenkins you'll find some information.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best way to do it, but I can't trust online repositories like TestFlight.

Not the easiest but rather secure workaround for this;

- Get your customers device into your developer account
- Create your new development provisioning profiles (consisting that device)
- Distribute your application via Archive, and save it
- Send your IPA to your customer

Comment: Sounds good for me, but probably for my customer it could be too complex to make it working

Comment: first phase is you get his device and do the first 3. He/she is just going to download the IPA (from his/her mail?) and double click on it. iTunes recognizes it automatically, and uploads the IPA on the device.